# Hiding icon based on Context in RecyclerAdapter giving null pointer

Tags: android

In my Adapter I check if the context is an instance of a certain Activity. And if it's an instance, I would hide the icon.

```
public ViewHolderRootComment(@NonNull View itemView) {
       super(itemView);

       if(mContext instanceof CommentReplyActivity){
            itemView.findViewById(R.id.vh_fragevent_singlecommentroot_iv_reply).setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }else{
            vhRootReplyButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.vh_fragevent_singlecommentroot_iv_reply);
            vhRootReplyButton.setOnClickListener(this);
       }
}
```

However the problem is, once the icon is hidden in my viewholder's onclick method, it gives me a nullpointer when I'm checking for the viewId.

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            mPosition = getAdapterPosition();
            int viewId = view.getId();

            if(viewId == vhRootProfilePicture.getId()){
                ...                
            }else if(viewId == vhRootHeartButton.getId()){
                ...    
            }else if(viewId == vhRootReplyButton.getId()){  <------ null pointer on the hidden icon


            }
        }
```

There are no errors unless I click near the hidden icon in the viewholder.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.ImageView.getId()' on a null object reference
        at com.sewaconnect.adapters.CommentsAdapter$ViewHolderRootComment.onClick(CommentsAdapter.java:199)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I have also tried checking if the view is null first but that also doesn't seem to work

```
else if(viewId == vhRootReplyButton.getId() && vhRootReplyButton.getId() != null){
```

also tried checking the R.id

```
}else if(viewId == vhRootReplyButton.getId() && itemView.findViewById(R.id.vh_fragevent_singlecommentroot_iv_reply) != null){
```

Comment: You're only assigning `vhRootReplyButton` if `mContext` is not a `CommentReplyActivity`. Is that really what you mean to do? In any case, checking against the `R.id` instead of `vhRootReplyButton.getId()` would prevent that NPE.

Comment: I tried checking for it but it's still giving me the error

Comment: It can't be the same error, then, if we're saying the same thing. How did you do it, exactly? I meant `if (viewId == R.id.vh_fragevent_singlecommentroot_iv_reply)`, and you can do that for all of those `if`s. That's generally how it's done, anyway, rather than with `getId()`.

Comment: The part that was giving me an error was when I called ```.getId()``` again. I think it's because I set visibility to gone and was trying to ```getId()``` on a null reference. But it was fixed when I did it your way using ```(viewId == R.id.vh_fragevent_singlecommentroot_iv_reply)``` for all my if statements. Thanks a bunch for helping me debug, really appreciate it.

Comment: Nah, it was nothing to do with the visibility. It was because you only assigned `vhRootReplyButton` when you weren't hiding it. When `mContext` is a `CommentReplyActivity`, you never do `vhRootReplyButton = itemView.findViewById(...);`, so `vhRootReplyButton` was null in that case. Anyhoo, no problem. Glad you got it working. Cheers!